# How to set multi-dimensional array value in statically compiled Groovy?

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have a Groovy multi-dimensional array:

```
boolean[][] arr = new boolean[10][10]
```

Then I also have a boolean value:

```
boolean value = true
```

Now I want to set the value of one array element:

```
arr[1][1] = value
```

This works fine in "default" Groovy. However, as soon as I add the `@CompileStatic` annotation to the class, the last line above gives me the following error message:

*Error:(91, 25) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot assign value of type boolean to variable of type boolean[]*

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Which version of Groovy?

Comment: That surprises me.  Can you show a more complete code sample that doesn't work and also indicate which version of Grails you are using?

Comment: I am using Groovy version 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I can compile and run this under Groovy 2.1.6

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] arge) {
        boolean[][] arr = new boolean[10][10];
        boolean value = true;
        arr[1][1] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I didn't use `1` as index directly, but a variable `i`. That variable was defined with `def`, but not with `int`. After changing that the problem does not occur any more.